# TextBlock FontSize Animation not work with Duration in Xaml in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, storyboard, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I just create a C# Windows Universal App Project (Visual Studio 2015),

It works fine with

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="mainTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
```

but this doesn't

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="mainTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"/>
```

only works when I set the duration to 0

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="mainTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"/>
```

but I read some tutorial, they set duration for changing font size, so what I miss ?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution,

needs to add property

> EnableDependentAnimation="True"

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" To="0" 
EnableDependentAnimation="True" 
Storyboard.TargetName="mainTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"/>
```